# Grub rescue even with no hard drive in the pc

Tags: grub2, hard-drive

i installed ubuntu to give it a try i decided i wanted my windows back and got the typical grub problem... now i decided to just remove the hdd with it on and install windows to a seperate hdd... i removed the ubuntu hdd and tried booting with no hdd installed at all... still get the grub error and i dont see how as there is no storage in the pc at all, anyone know how this is possible?.... answers on a post card

Comment: have you tried it with super-grub ? available here - right field of: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ - it copes well with grub2 installation on your puter. content with this post-card ?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's *some* device in your computer that has a MBR (master boot record) that contains Grub as a boot loader. Maybe a CD-ROM with a live distribution, a floppy disk (if your computer still has a floppy drive), a flash drive or anything down that alley. One way to find out is booting a live distribution like Knoppix and using a tool like `hwinfo` to browser through your systems hardware.

Comment: no i have no media or storage device attached at all it was the first thing i did, i want to install windows on a new drive as a master os and format the old hard-drive place it in a carrage and use it as a usb external... i have to admit though the more i use linux the more i like it! i may just keep it as a secondary os on the drive its on..... but still with no hardware attached to the laptop at all im getting a gub rescue error and as far as i knew that only could come from something on a storage or media devive.... its confusing me lol

Comment: Like I wrote, I'd recommend to get a live distribution like Knoppix and rummage through what tools like `hwinfo` can find. Maybe there's an SSD in your laptop, or a small hard disc meant for a rescue or recovery system or something like that.